# Which function represents this set of data?

Tags: regression

So, I've done a multiple regression analysis of a certain data base, got the coefficients, and then calculated the y values using the variables from the database. The y values represent the "overall strength" of a participant in the battle, positive favouring the attacker. In the data base, there are two variables representing accomplishments of the participants and I've computed a variable representing attacker winning, defender winning or a draw, based on those two variables.

How would I plot this graph myself? Which cumulative distribution function is it? Can it even be constructed in one go in any software or should they be plotted separately and then overlapped somehow?

[image: the graph in question]

Comment: None of the graphs in your plot can possibly represent a CDF, because none of them are monotonic.